# ModX Evo: Where is OnPageNotFound in Systemevents?

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-301, modx, modx-evolution

I am trying to install NG!Redirect 0.0.2 but am stuck at the 2nd step on the installation guide. It instructs:

```
Go to Systemevents..
- Check: "OnPageNotFound"
```

But I do not see that option. Its seems Syetem Events is a report, not a config doc.

Does anyone know the correct way of installing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Elements > Manage Elements > Plugins > NG!Redirect > System Events tab, then check OnPageNotFound and save.